# how to integrate one project file to another in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Hello friends I developed an app in ios in  that contains a database (coredata) the user can login with a username and a password and then he can store the personal details, pictures, files, documents.... Now, I want to link this Xcode project to another code project of mine so can anyone help how to add one Xcode project file to another. I tried by adding new files in Xcode but it was not showing project file which I want to add hope I'll get the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `.xcodeproj` you want to add in the file selector in the sidebar of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to move the files into a separate directory, treat it as a separate project and put that project under revision control. Then link it to your two other projects as a submodule.